# How can I change the color of the active nav-pills?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to change the color blue when scrolling through the page. How do I go about that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you included jQuery? Have you included the JS for Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason that the `background-color` declaration isn't being applied to your `.active` class is that your CSS selector is wrong. It should be:

`.nav>li.active>a`

not:

`.nav>li>a.active`

As for changing the color on scroll, what do you mean by that? What is the desired end goal? Do you want the color to transition to an alternative color once the user scrolls to a specified point on your page? Do you want the color to incrementally change as the user scrolls?

More information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.nav>li>a.active` instead `.nav>li.active` to change the color